# How to add "Remove Item" to WooCommerce checkout using a hook?

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I've customized the [`checkout/review-order.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php) template file to include the "remove item" functionality on the WooCommerce checkout.

The reason for this is that I did not know how to make the same thing using a hook.

The goal is to be able to remove the product from the cart directly from the checkout page by using the `functions.php` file instead of modifying the template.

This is the modified version of the template:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.8.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>"> 
                <td class="product-name">
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                <?php
                echo apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                sprintf(
                '<a class="remove-from-checkout" href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">Delete</a>',
                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_id() ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                ),
                $cart_item_key
                );
                ?>
                <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                </td>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

---

More specifically, this is the piece of code I added between lines 39 and 40

```php
<?php
echo apply_filters(
'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
sprintf(
'<a class="remove-from-checkout" href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">Delete</a>',
esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
esc_attr( $_product->get_id() ),
esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
),
$cart_item_key
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your customized template `woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity` is the nearest hook just before it, so you can include in it the remove link code block this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'checkout_review_order_remove_link', 1000, 3);
function checkout_review_order_remove_link($quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    return $quantity_html . apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove">X</a>',
        esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
        esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
        esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
    ), $cart_item_key);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: It works, but it also generates an error message. `Deprecated: Non-static method WC_Cart::get_remove_url() should not be called statically`

Comment: I had to copy the code from the template into your code to make it work. `'<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove">X</a>',
esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),`